# Firebase not recognized when running jest unit test

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs

I am trying to write test scripts to get get code coverage of a .js file that interacts with a firebase realtime database. This is the code i am trying to test. Here is the firebase initialization in the index.js  file...

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyADFcVF0FfSzIyZjCL0T8Wf1jH9NA_tPqM",
    authDomain: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://realtimedatabase-d0a3e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e",
    storageBucket: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "74578194003",
    appId: "1:74578194003:web:302a3001f78fd4ee84a0a6",
    measurementId: "G-QVGMEM66ZC"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

This is the method in the index.js file that i want to test...

```
function writeUserData(userEmail, Password) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var usersRef = database.ref('Users');
    var newUser = usersRef.push({
        user_email: userEmail,
        user_password: Password,
    });
    var key = newUser.key;//unique key
    return true;
    console.log(key);
}
module.exports = writeUserData;
```

All i need to do is see the method returns true. In my index.test.js I have the following test...

```
const index = require('./index');

test('validates write user data', () => {
    expect(writeUserData('test','test')).toBe(true);
});
```

I am getting an error saying firebase is not defined. Any suggestions?

```
● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

      14 | };
      15 | // Initialize Firebase
    > 16 | firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
         | ^
      17 | firebase.analytics();
      18 | //test for github
      19 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (index.test.js:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
```

EDIT: This is how I am getting the firebase libraries in index.js...

(This is in the index.html)

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script src = "index.js"></script>
```

This is the full index.js file

```
var attemptLogin = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
var adminSetCode = 1234;



var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyADFcVF0FfSzIyZjCL0T8Wf1jH9NA_tPqM",
    authDomain: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://realtimedatabase-d0a3e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e",
    storageBucket: "realtimedatabase-d0a3e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "74578194003",
    appId: "1:74578194003:web:302a3001f78fd4ee84a0a6",
    measurementId: "G-QVGMEM66ZC"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//test for github


// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validateLogin(){
    var username = document.getElementById("emailLogin").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;
    verifyUserCredentials(username, password, function(bool){
      if (bool){
          alert("Login successful");
          window.location.href = "homeEmpl.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
          return true;
      }
      else{
          attemptLogin --;// Decrementing by one.
          alert("You have left "+attemptLogin+" attempt;");
          // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
          if( attemptLogin == 0){
              document.getElementById("emailLogin").disabled = true;
              document.getElementById("passwordLogin").disabled = true;
              document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
          return false;
          }
      }
    });
}


function writeUserData(userEmail, Password) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var usersRef = database.ref('Users');
    var newUser = usersRef.push({
        user_email: userEmail,
        user_password: Password,
    });
    var key = newUser.key;//unique key
    return true;
    console.log(key);
}
module.exports = writeUserData;

function checkUserExists(userEmail, Password, callback){
    var database = firebase.database();
    var usersRef = database.ref('Users');
    var exists = false;
    usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var childEmail = childData.user_email;
            if (childEmail == userEmail) {
              exists = true;
            }
        });
        console.log(exists);
        callback(exists);
    });
}

function verifyUserCredentials(userEmail, Password, callback){
    var database = firebase.database();
    var usersRef = database.ref('Users');
    var exists = false;
    usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var childEmail = childData.user_email;
            var childPassword = childData.user_password;
            if (childEmail == userEmail && childPassword == Password) {
              exists = true;
            }
        });
        console.log(exists);
        callback(exists);
    });
}

function validateAdmin(){
    var adminCode = document.getElementById("adminPass").value;
    if (adminCode != adminSetCode){
        alert("Invalid Admin credentials")
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Welcome, Admin.")
        window.location.href = "homeMng.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
        return true;
    }
}

function validateRegister(){
    var email = document.getElementById("emailRegister").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordRegister").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("passwordRegister2").value;
    checkUserExists(email,password, function(bool){
        if ( password2 != password){
            alert ("Passwords do not match.");
            return false;
        }
        //Ignore Email Authentication for now. Will add firebase auth
        /*
        else if (!emails.includes(email)){
            alert("Email not verified.")
            return false;
        }
        */
        else if (bool){
            alert("Email already registered.")
            return false;
        }
        else{
            writeUserData(email,password);
            alert("Account Created!")
            window.location.href = "index.html";
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I am currently trying to write a test that can verify writeUserData returns true. I am currently only trying to mock a real time database atm.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant code into the question itself.  Don't link to outside resources, as they might become stale over time, and unhelpful to others in the future.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. In addition to @DougStevenson, please check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should avoid listing outside sources if possible, and always write the code in the question itself. That way, the person who wishes to answer can copy and paste the code in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend to review mocking in jest https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have read the documentation but am still lost on how to mock the database and recognize firebase. Would you be able to write a short example test

Comment: Where in your tests are you importing your firebase app (firebase index.js) and mocking the specific methods used? This would be effectively how the documentation indicates to mock modules.

Comment: Also please clarify how you are importing firebase libraries such as auth, database, etc

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky are the edits what you were looking for?